# Responsive image scaling with changing max-height

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, scaling

It's far simpler to point to an example than to try and explain the problem I am trying to solve so I'll do just that (apologies to people on mobile, this won't work...)

The effect I want to achieve can be seen on VICE news (http://news.vice.com)

As you can see while resizing the browser, the aspect ratio of the image remains intact throughout certain sizes. It jumps at 1200px and again at 700px, all the while scaling both the width and the height.

Is there a way to achieve this using only CSS? My head is stuck on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries, of course.

If you look in their source code, you will see that they have 3 different versions of the same image to display at each different size (to minimize scaling). Then, by using media queries, they will display the proper one and have its width fill the page:

Here's the mobile image, for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 43.75em)
{
    .lede .lede-images img.mobile
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And here's the global code:

```
.lede .lede-images img.mobile
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Setting the width to 100% while not setting the height will automatically maintain the aspect ratio while resizing.